# Color from shape in excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to change the color of a cell depending on the color of a shape.
Does anyone know how to GET the color of a shape using VBA?
Thank you

Comment: What have you found out already? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193908.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A super simple example to set the color of the active cell to the color of a Shape:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim shp As Shape

    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
    v = shp.Fill.ForeColor
    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = v
End Sub
```

[image]